# How to Handle custom url parameters from changing the output in PHP

Tags: php, html, url, parameters

This is my first time... I am writing a code for a festival wishing site with php which has a "share on WhatsApp" button. 
WhatsApp Share Button:

```
<div id="share" style="margin-top:8px;"  onclick="window.open('whatsapp://send?text=*<?php echo $_GET['n'];?>*+Sent+you+a+Special+Message+:%0a1.+Touch+this+blue+line++*<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>*%0a2.+Enter+Your+Name.')">
```

When the url parameters are `www.example.com/wish.php?n=Advik` it works fine and I gets the desired text to be shared on WhatsApp but when the url parameters are 
`example.com/wish.php?n=Advik&x=10&y=36`   I get this result:

> *Advik* Sent you a Special Message :
>   1. Touch this blue line  http://findadvik.ooo/wish.php?n=Advik {*note- second line is missing.}

But I should get the result that I get in first parameter:

> *Advik* Sent you a Special Message :
>   1. Touch this blue line  http://findadvik.ooo/wish.php?n=Advik
>   2. Enter Your Name.

*NOTE -- I am using a free hosting service so it is impossible to remove extra parameters and I am using Android Device & I am using PHP with HTML5 & Live demo at http://www.FindAdvik.ooo/wish.php?n=Advik&x=10&y=36

Comment: Please [see here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) to learn how to format properly.

Comment: You need to [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the URL that you are putting in the message.

Comment: ...and How do I do Urlencode... Plz help

Comment: By reading the documentation in the link I provided above.